# How to avoid showing consent screen in our own native apps when external authentication?

Tags: android, security, authentication, oauth-2.0, openid-connect

#### Background

- We have developed a web application featuring a rest-api using oauth2/oidc and support for third party apps
- We have developed our own native apps for android and ios. Currently they retrieve a long lived token from user credential flow (no consent screen needed).
- We are currently extending our authentication flow to also accept external login by google/office365. This is also supported by specifying acr value in authorization code/implicit oauth flow.

#### Issue/Problem

- We of course want to be able to fully trust our native app and not show a consent screen for the best user experience. While using the authorization code/implicit flow though nothing can be considered a secret and a malicious hacker could potentially exploit (without user knowledge) the user if no consent screen is shown.
- How can we avoid having to show consent screen for our own native app while still being sure user is as safe as possible?

#### How to solve?

1. Doing a separate office365/google login to retrieve refresh token from this idp and then implementing a way to publicly authenticate using this token to retrieve a longlived token from our webapp.
2. Simply ignore security flaw and never ask for user consent given the nonsecret mix of `clientId/clientSecret/redirectUrl` with the excuse "it's quite difficult to hack this".
3. Ignoring security flaw if external login with the excuse "google/office365 should show a consent screen anyhow when requesting a refresh token".
4. Some unknown way to make sure that its not a malicious app/user

The reason i don't like (1) above is it both opens up a somewhat new authentication flow in our webapp and forces native app to implement a more complex authentication flow.

Is there something im missing here, what would be considered best practise?

Comment: Wouldn't there be a way to do it similar to a web app?  You have the same properties then - the clientId/secret lives in the web app, and the native app must go that way to access it?  Off course the web app endpoints could be misused, but that's true of normal web apps as well…

Comment: How is this any different from not going through the webapp security wise?

Comment: Security becomes "the same".  The webapp has it's own specialized backend, and perhaps won't expose the authenticated users profile, depending on the purpose of the app.  If the webapp exposes something that requires a specific clientId, then that could be just as misused as the app's client identifications.  This probably doesn't solve your problems, but they _should_ be considered similar if you regard the app as you regard the browser.

Answer (score 0):

The point is that Google needs to authenticate the user outside of your app to make sure your app does not see the user credentials and thus defeat the purpose of OAuth.

The user also needs to allow the app explicitly to avoid random apps obtaining tokens from the user: anyone with a Google account can create a `client_id`/`client_secret`/`redirect_uri` combo. You/your app is not trusted by Google with tokens for arbitrary users without asking those users first. As you mention at (1) the user only needs to go through this once. The app may retrieve a long-lived refresh token and keep using that to refresh access tokens.

Hence best practice is to spawn a browser/webview and handle the authentication/consent flow in there. There's no way around that. If there was a way it would be a vulnerability because the system was designed to avoid it.

Comment: Maybe a slight missunderstanding, what we want to avoid is the consent screen that our own application shows for all native apps using a webview. When combined with the google/o365 authentication this will mean theres actually one consent screen for each resource (google and us). For our self-developed (and trusted) apps we are looking for a way to avoid our own consent screen when using external authentication.

Answer (score 0):

I'd say something like nr 2:

Have a way to mark a client (identified by clientId and clientSecret) as **trusted** (e.g. with a superuser interface), and thereby automatically give consent.

The client secret should be safe; if it's not, you have other security problems.

Comment: ClientSecret in a native app is considered not to be safe, for other webapps we already do this.

Comment: You're right…  I'm more used to thinking in web apps.